# Cloudformation automatic calculation values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a Cloudformation template and in this template the customer selects the instance type they want according to the load. I wondered if there is something I can have this calculated automatically. For example, the user can just enter a value and based on that value the CF will automatically select the instance type. I can do this in Bash script etc but I wondered if there is a more accurate way.

Comment: What is the type of value for load? Is it an int that represents a percentage? Like 100%? Maybe its a number like requests per second for a web server? Can you give me some example load numbers and instance types?